# Batch: Errorlevels not working in some situations

Tags: batch-file, robocopy, errorlevel

Let me first explain what I am trying to accomplish: I have a GoPro camera and when recording multiple time-lapses you end up with a big pile of img files, two time-lapses are divided by a number in the file name. Gxxxyyyy is how the files are labeled, the y stands for which time-lapse the picture belongs to and x what picture in the time-lapse.

I am trying to create a program that puts every time-lapse in a different folder (sorting by the numbers on the x position); I am using batch because I already had some experience with it.

This is the program I wrote:

```
@echo off
set loop=0
set fn=1
set session=1

:sort
if %loop% LSS 1000 (

if %fn% GTR 99 (

    ROBOCOPY D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures\Session%session% G%fn%*.JPG
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 set /A session=%session%+1
)
if %fn% LSS 10 (

    ROBOCOPY D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures\Session%session% G00%fn%*.JPG
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 set /A session=%session%+1        
) ELSE (

    if %fn% LSS 100 (
ROBOCOPY D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures\Session%session% G0%fn%*.JPG
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 set /A session=%session%+1
    )
)

set /A fn=%fn%+1
set /A loop=%loop%+1
goto sort
)
```

I was trying to use the errorlevel value to determine if the copy was successful, because if it was the next copy had to be to another folder which is what i used the session variable for. But it always copies everything into the "session1" folder and not into separate folders even though i have files with different numbers on the x position.

I tried figuring out what the problem was and used "echo %ERRORLEVEL%" followed by a pause, right after the robocopy commands and every time it just said 0 even though files were copied.

That is the issue and I can't figure out why the errorvalue doesn't change.

Comment: An errorlevel of 0 indicates success.

Comment: @indiv according to this page an errorvalue of 1 is what I am trying to acomplish: http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Comment: `ERRORLEVEL` is a built-in value, not an environmental variable, so you don't need the `%` around it. `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` is the usual way you test for it being set; note there are no `%` and it doesn't use `EQU`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you try to expand errorlevel inside of a block.

The percent expansion is done by the parser when the block is parsed, before the block is executed.

You should change the expansion to delayed expansion.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set loop=0
set fn=1
set session=1

:sort
if %loop% LSS 1000 (

    if !fn! GTR 99 (
        ROBOCOPY D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures D:\Bureaublad\Output\Pictures\Session!session! G!fn!*.JPG
        if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 1 set /A session=session+1
    )
....
)
```

Comment: I am not that great of an programmer could you explain what a parser, block and delayed expansion are. I understand that the solution given above works but is not the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`ERRORLEVEL` is a built-in variable, not an environmental variable, and so you shouldn't use the percent signs (`%`) around it, and simply test directly for the value. The proper way to use it is simply

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 DoSomething
```

Comment: No, you should NOT use it without percents, as then you don't test for equality, instead you test if errorlevel is 1 or greater

Comment: @jeb: The [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335.aspx) clearly says it's without percents. Unless you have a citation to prove otherwise, you're incorrect. Direct quote from that page, second code block example: `if not errorlevel 1 goto end`. (The poster also indicated in a comment to the original question that this information solved the problem.)

Comment: You reference the `IF ERRORLEVEL <number>`syntax of the IF command, but this results in many problems, as it's not obviously that it doesn't compare for equality. But `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU <number>` uses the standard syntax of the `IF` command and is more clearly. Btw. the documentation is incorrect and/or incomplete on so many points, that it shouldn't be referenced

Comment: @jeb: What about [Raymond Chen's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx). He typically knows exactly what he's talking about, I believe. He says the two are not the same, and that you don't need the %s.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [robocopy exit codes](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html)

look at this:

> Bugs
>   Version XP026 returns a success errorlevel even when it fails.